# "Not" operator in validation rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a custom validation rule, `is_admin`, that checks if a user is an administrator.

Does Laravel have an "opposite" operator (like how `!` works in PHP), such that I can do something like `not:is_admin`, which would check that the user *isn't* an admin:

```
$rules = array(
    'user_id' => 'required|numeric|not:is_admin'
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    // return error
}
else
{
    // continue
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to negate a validation rule. You'll just have to write a separate rule for `is_not_admin` :).

Comment: That's unfortunately true. Just remember to reuse your existing is_admin rule: function is_not_admin(args...) = !is_admin(args...)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes we can** by using conditional statements on rules array.

$rules is an array that we pass to validation class or define in Request class.

**Example #1:**

```
public function rules{
    //here we return an array of rules like shown below.
   return [
       'field_a'  => 'required',
       'field_b' => 'required',
   ];
//we can add any operator by a little change.
 save validation rules array in variable like shown below.
 $rules = [
      'field_a' => 'required',
      'field_b' => 'required',
 ];

 //now we can add any rule in $rules array using common ways of writing conditional statements.

//For example field_c is required only when field_a is present and field_b is not
     if(isset($this->field_a) && !isset($this->field_b)){
         $rules['field_c' => 'required'];
     }
   //we can apply any kind of conditional statement and add or remove validation rules on the basis of our business logic.
}
```

**Example#2**

```
public function rules(){

    $rules = [];

    if ($this->attributes->has('some-key')) {
         $rules['other-key'] = 'required|unique|etc';
    }

    if ($this->attributes->get('some-key') == 'some-value') {
          $rules['my-key'] = 'in:a,b,c';
    }

    if ($this->attributes->get('some-key') == 'some-value') {
        $this->attributes->set('key', 'value');
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can validate it through `required_if:field,value`.
You can check more details at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-required-if

Or you can use `not_in:foo,bar`.
You can check more details at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-not-in